# Testing series $ \sum\limits_{n= 1}^{\infty} \sin{\frac{n + \sin(n)}{3n + 1}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem which is related to testing the divergence or convergence of a series. For more detail:
$$
\sum\limits_{n= 1}^{\infty} \sin{\frac{n + \sin(n)}{3n + 1}}
$$
I find it hard here because inside $\sin(n)$ does not go to $0$ but $\frac{1}{3} $ when $n \rightarrow \infty$, therefore, I don't know if I can conclude it is convergent here or not

Comment: It depends on the value(s). If, for instance, it goes to $317\pi$, then your situation is the same as if it went to $0$.

Comment: For every series $\sum\limits_k^\infty a_k$ if we take $S_n=\sum\limits_k^n a_k$ and if $\sum\limits_k^\infty a_k=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} S_n$ converges to $S$, then $a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (S_n-S_{n-1})=S-S=0$ so if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n\ne 0$ the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Using the n-th term test:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\sin{\frac{1}{3}} \neq 0$$
Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ diverges.